# jQuery / CSS precedence when setting/overriding background-color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, coffeescript

I'm using jQuery to `addClass` to a hovered over `div`...but the background color won't change. I'm guessing it's because it has previously been assigned a background-color in CSS? Other properties (border) on the `hover` class appear when hovering so `addClass` is working.

How can/should I make this work?

jQuery

```
$('.pick1-box').hover( 
    -> $(this).addClass('hover')
    -> $(this).removeClass('hover')
    )
```

CSS

```
.pick1-box, .pick2-box {
    ...
    background: #eee;
    ...
}

.hover {
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

html

```
...
<li class='nominee clearfix' id='146'>
  <div class='candidate'>
    <img alt="Enders" height="80" src="/assets/25803sm.jpg" />
    Dick Waddington
  </div>
  <div class='pick-boxes'>
    <div class='pick1-box'>
      1
    </div>
    <div class='pick2-box'>
      2
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
...
```

Comment: You add the class and then immediately remove it? The browser likely doesn't even have time to draw in the changes from the class being added before it's already removed.

Comment: @Marc B: That's [CoffeeScript syntax](http://coffeescript.org#functions).

Comment: Ah well, when the heading says "jquery" and uses js-invalid syntax, gotta wonder...

Comment: @BoltClock. So what does `->` mean?

Comment: @gdoron: It's a shorthand for `function() { ... }`

Comment: Curious, why don't you just use the `:hover` pseudo-class? Are you supporting IE6?

Comment: Also, your given code has syntax errors. There's a missing `)` in your jQuery and a missing `}` in your CSS.

Comment: Ya. I just cut and pasted. tried to add ellipsis. i'll clean up.

Comment: We will have to see more of your code. Your given code works fine by itself: http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/h2HYC

Comment: @BoltClock: I tried the pseudo class but it didn't work either. Not sure why...can only assume it's because I've attached `click` events to the div via jQuery. Though not entirely sure. Javascript clearly not my forté.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you're loading jquery and code but try this:

```
    .hover {
    background-color: yellow !important;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but this is generally considered to be a bad practice.  `important` should really only be used as a last resort.  It is often a sign of bad design.

Comment: yes it is. But without knowing the correct order of css declarations... it seemed the easiest way to solve it. Anyway avoid it as much as you can

Answer (score 0):

You could make the 2nd rule more specific:

```
.pick1-box.hover, .pick2-box.hover {
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

[css specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

This assumes that your `.hover` css actually occurs prior to the `.pick1-box` rule as these have equal specificity, the one which occurs later will have precedence.

Comment: No change. Border turns red but background still grey (#eee)

Comment: appreciate the specificity link though!

Answer (score 0):

You can try re-ordering or adding an important to your CSS, or you could do something like:

```
$('.pick1-box').hover($(this).attr('style', 'background-color: yellow;border: 1px solid red;'),$(this).removeAttr('style'));
```

since element styles take precedence.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as you've stated, is because the style has been overridden in the style attribute of the element being affected. You have a couple of options:

1. [Don't change the element's css directly.](http://jsfiddle.net/3RrdW/3/)
2. [Use !important on the settings you absolutely need to override element styles.](http://jsfiddle.net/3RrdW/1/)
3. [Change the element's css directly, but remove them once you're done with them.](http://jsfiddle.net/3RrdW/5/)

Comment: I think I'm confused. **Re: #1 don't change css directly:** but, I'm don't believe I was, in this case (though `$(this).css('background-color', 'yellow')` worked). I'm just adding a class tag.